# MVC 5 Authentication and HttpClient No MediaTypeFormatter is available

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC 5 Web Api and a desktop app that connects to it.

I have a controller and connect  to it from the app without any issue, but when I put the `[Authorize]` attribute in the controller, the `httpclient` in desktop app stops working and says that there is not MediaTypeFormatter available.

I think the HttpClient is working fine, I tried defining authentication using the request header:
`httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization`
and using this way `httpclient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "password") });`.

In the pass using MVC 4 it works with authentication.

In this case, wit MVC 5, it works perfectly when using Anonymous, but when I authenticate I get this exception in the `httpresponse.Content.ReadAsAsync`

```
No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Dictionary`2' from content with media type 'text/html'.
```

Where should I see?

**Update**

I read the httpResponse as a string, to see what the httpclient is getting and I in the string the HTML of the login page. Aparently the authentication fails and the MVC + API redirects to the login page.
What should I do now?
Why the authentication doesnt work like in the previous MVC 4 web API? Is because the new OWIN authentication?

Comment: From the details that you mentioned in the post, it looks like server is responding back with an error probably with the details in a html document and that is the reason the response content type is `text/html`. By default Web API ships with formatters for `json`, `xml` and `formurlencoded` and so does the ReadAsAync understands only these formats...try this..do `httpresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` to get the html and check what error you are seeing..

Comment: @KiranChalla you are great! I update my answer based on your sugestion

Comment: Are you storing the cookie when authenticating and passing it to the server when you need to do authentication stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These issue was because the authentication was not working. MVC5 use Web Forms authentication, so I had to cread a new way to authenticate the HttpClient.

- Make a Get to the /Account/Login page and read the _RequestVerificationToken
- Post to /Account/Login the UserName, Password, and _RequestVerificationToken

The error was because, when authentication fails, MVC5 redirects the HttpClient to the Login Page. So I was not getting JSON, I was getting HTML. The HTML of the Login Page.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

httpClient.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/json";

Comment: I am not reading Strings from the web sever. I am reading Dictionarys or objects...

Comment: I added httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")). Still get No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Dictionary`2' from content with media type 'text/html'. In the Web Api by default is returning JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This article should be helpful.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication

It is telling us that we need to implement the authentication handler for Web API.

And I think Web API is a stand alone project type in VS2013, make sure you are not using MVC which is using forms authentication by default.

If you have to use the whole MVC package, then you have to make a http post to login page like Ricardo Polo said, and then attach the cookie you got to every api call. For example:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://{0}/login", server));
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

bool loginSuccess = false;

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    //If there's a cookie in the response, it means login successful, 
    //and the cookie is the one returned by the server that can be used to identify
    //the client when calling Authorized api calls.
    loginSuccess = (response.Cookies.Count > 0);
}
response.Close();

//Now make a request to the api
HttpWebRequest ApiRequest = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://{0}/api/values", server));
ApiRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
ApiRequest.CookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies[0]);
//From here add code to get the response.
```

The above code can be done using HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

I have exception like that when my Action input parameter was Dictionary, i solved it by creating custom Model which holds all my input parameters and Dictionary and after that it was working

Answer (score 0):

MVC 5 Web API (Web API 2) templates in Visual Studio uses Token based OWIN middle-ware for authentication.

Read the following article:

Authenticate and Get a Bearer Token 
http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/authentication/individual-accounts-in-aspnet-web-api

```
In the Fiddler Composer tab, enter the following URL (remember to change "port" to the actual port number):

http://localhost:port/Token

Leave the request method as POST. Change the Content-Type header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Replace the request body with the following:

grant_type=password&username=Alice&password=password123

Click Execute to send the request. Here is the raw HTTP request:

POST http://localhost:49436/Token HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:49436
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 55

grant_type=password&username=Alice&password=password123
```

In MVC 5 Web API templates you can enable cookie based authentication but to get Authenticated you need to use the /Token end point by sending a Http Post message with the form body having three fields 1. grant_type 2. username  3. password.

In response to this message you will get a JSON object in which you can find access_token (which you can ignore if you dont want to use Token based authorization) and the server will set a cookie if the use cookie authentication is configured (default). By default controllers derived from ApiControllers does not use cookie authentication in some of the VS templates. You need to store the access_token and place it in header of all further requests  to ApiController's. Http header should be like: 
`Authorization: Bearer [place_accesstoken_without_sorrunding_braces]`